# Android mock Power Manager in robolectrict unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric

Hi i am trying to add a mocked version of Power manager in my unit tests but cant seem to find in the documentations in robolectric 3.2.2 on how to use a custom shadow context?

Here is my code:

```
 activityController = Robolectric.buildActivity(activityClass).withIntent(intent).attach();
        activity = activityController.create().get();
 PowerManager mockPowerManager = Mockito.mock(PowerManager.class);
        Mockito.when(mockPowerManager.isScreenOn()).thenReturn(false);

        ShadowContextImpl shadowContext = new ShadowContextImpl();
        shadowContext.setSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE, mockPowerManager);
```

How do i inject or add the shadowContext into the activity i am testing on?

Comment: Can you share code that you want to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the ShadowPowerManager instead of Mockito

```
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) RuntimeEnvironment.application.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
ShadowPowerManager shadowPowerManager = shadowOf(powerManager);
shadowPowerManager.setIsScreenOn(false);
```